# select and operate on words from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to underline words from an array if a condition is met but I can only select the index as a variable, how can I make it into an element and then underline it (if that's possible). Here is some code to show what I mean.

```
var textArr = $(div).text().split(/\b/);

for (i = 0; i < textArr.length; i++) {

    if ($('#search').val().match(new RegExp(textArr[i], "i"))) {

     //pseudo code
      $(textArr[i]).css('text-decoration','underline');
    }
}
```

Comment: How about throwing a fiddle together for us so we can more easily help you?

Comment: I like this problem, definitely will work on it if there's a fiddle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't involve loops. A sample solution is available  [at this **jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrRampage/JzLjd/3/):

### HTML

```
<label>
    Highlight:
    <input type="text" id="search" 
        placeholder="Enter a regular expression"/>
</label>
<!-- Text to underline below -->
<p id="toUnderline"> ... </p>
```

### CSS

```
em {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

### jQuery Code

```
$('#search').on('change', function(e) {
    highlight('#toUnderline', $(this).val());
});

function highlight(selector, search) {
    var target = $(selector);
    var re = new RegExp(search, 'i');
    var wrapper = '<em>';
    target.html(
        target.text()
            .match(/\w+/g)
            .map(function (word) {
            return (word.search(re) > -1 
                    ? $(wrapper)
                        .text(word)
                        .wrap('<p>')
                        .parent()
                        .html()
                    : word);
        }).join(' ')
    );
}
```

[edit] Updated the code to be more modular and reusable. Unfortunately, this code will strip out double spaces...

Comment: thanks for the fiddle. I can use a lot of that code +1

Comment: Thanks! You helped me break 1000 points. ;) Good luck with your code!

Comment: If you have time, would you mind checking this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JzLjd/6/. I am trying to make multiple target divs, but it's not going well. Thanks

Comment: Have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MrRampage/JzLjd/7/). You need to run the `.each` function and apply that code to each of the matches.

Comment: That's great. I had tried using the each function, but I was getting the strings being copied and concatenated with each iteration. I must have had something in the wrong order. You have been a massive help. Thank you very much, glad I could help tip you over to 4 figures. ;)

Comment: Please provide feedback on down votes. I would like to improve my answers and coding. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To turn your psuedo code, this might be a solution:

```
$('<span>'+textArr[i]+'</span>').css('text-decoration','underline')
.appendTo('body'); // or any selector
```

Basically you're creating a new element and styling it with `.css()` and then append it to a container using `.append()`

Comment: it's good, but it adds the new underlined text next to the other text instead of replacing it. Thanks +1

Comment: @user2014429 what is the text you want to replace?

Comment: inthe div from: var textArr = $(div).text().split(/\b/);

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't posted the contents of `search`, I'm assuming it's a single word.

This jQuery function, [borrowed from here](http://www.gotoquiz.com/web-coding/programming/javascript/highlight-words-in-text-with-jquery/), should do exactly what you need.

```
jQuery.fn.underline = function (str, className) {
    var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType == 3 && regex.test(this.nodeValue);
        }).replaceWith(function() {
            return (this.nodeValue || "").replace(regex, function(match) {
                return "<span class=\"" + className + "\">" + match + "</span>";
            });
        });
    });
};

$("#textDiv").underline($("#search").text(), "underlinedText");
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/uKWhr/1/)